How to prevent session hijacking in ASP.NET MVC web with Identity?
Context
I have an ASP.NET MVC app on .NET 4.8 with Identity and Owin 2.2.4. It has 2FA enabled with ApplicationCookie and working perfectly fine.
Check this implementation of Startup.ConfigureAuth for more information:
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  { 
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
      ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
      SlidingExpiration = true,
      CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
      CookiePath = "/",
      CookieSameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
      Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
      {
          OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
  });

And this is how I login user in the AccountController:
private async Task SignInUser(ApplicationUser user, string authType)
{
      await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);

      var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, authType);
      var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false };

      AuthenticationManager.SignIn(authProperties, identity);
}
 

New requirement
There is way that user can login if they copy .AspNet.ApplicationCookie cookie and paste it into separate browser, this causes VAPT failure and session hijacking.
Now, I know that if someone has this cookie, then they should be able to log in. but in this case specifically, I want user to re-login even if they have cookie and trying to run in another browser.
Approaches I've considered so far:

Used a short-lived validateInterval (like TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)) for OnValidateIdentity in CookieAuthenticationProvider, it worked very well, but after my research I found that it would increase server load and impact performance as it has to query database or user-store every ten second.
Storing device or IP information during login, and validate it against the current session data.

But I'm not sure if this is a good idea, and so just wanted to confirm is there any more proper approach then this.
My question: how can I ensure user not able to login in different browsers even if they copy application cookie and in this case, how can I prompt them to re-login?
Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

You can make use of FingerprintJS. This is a browser fingerprinting library. The trial version is 14-days trial.

I can't say I'm convinced that this would help.

@ProgrammingLlama - U are right, is not a silver bullet, but it should decrease the hijack chances by a high percentage. As U saw it has 23.5k stars so is a serious project well appreciated.

Check out the capabilities of the AntiForgery tokens available in MVC.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages#validating-the-tokens
You should be able to use the IAntiForgeryAdditionalDataProvider to tie some specific detail(s) in the anti forgery cookie to details in your auth cookie (maybe the Description property?).  Then, you can handle the validation failure by clearing all auth data and redirecting to login like you would with any other auth timeout.

AntiForgery tokens have diff purpose @alex. I think I can not use it here. thanks for answering though.
